# A Clojure function that prints the “fully expanded form before evaluation”?

Tags: clojure, read-eval-print-loop

Is there a Clojure function that does for any function what `macroexpand-all` does for a macro?

In SICP, Abelson & Sussman give a demonstration of this that they call the “[linear recursive process](http://sarabander.github.io/sicp/html/1_002e2.xhtml#g_t1_002e2_002e2)”.

In other words, if we give:

```clojure
(factorial 6)
```

the function would *print* (and not evaluate):

```clj
(* 6 (* 5 (* 4 (* 3 (* 2 (1))))))
```

Essentially, I am trying to “see” the data structure *any* function “builds up” prior to evaluation.

---

I think this would be an interesting way for beginners (myself) to see what the Reader* is building up just before it passes things on to the Evaluator*.

*Not sure I’m using the right terms here.

Comment: By the way, my interest is motivated by my experience with https://pythontutor.com, a tool visualizing code execution

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Function tracing can be done without programming. It is, for example, available in the Cider extension to Emacs. https://docs.cider.mx/cider/debugging/tracing.html

I have loaded my factorial program into Emacs, and placed my cursor on the `factorial` function.

```
 (ns factorial.core
    (:gen-class))

 (defn factorial [n]
    (if (zero? n)
     1
     (* n (factorial (dec n)))))

 (defn -main
    "A factorial program."
    [& args]

    (let [n 6] 
       (println "The factorial of " n "is" (factorial n))))

             M-x cider-jack-in

 REPL:  (in-ns 'factorial.core)

             C-c M-t v, select factorial when prompted

        (factorial 3)
```

[image]

Comment: Yes! This is much closer to what I had in mind. I had not heard of function tracing before. Thank you for introducing me to it.

Answer (score 2):

This doesn't exist because that's not how evaluation works. The form `(* 6 (* 5 (* 4 (* 3 (* 2 1)))))` never exists while computing `(factorial 6)`, so the runtime can't just give it to you "in passing".

Comment: Thank you. Can you recommend a good place to read more about this? Perhaps a chapter in SICP that gets into this?

Comment: Into what, exactly? I'm confused about what you're doing - you're reading SICP, but asking about Clojure. But if you're currently reading 1.1.2, then I suspect you will find answers to many of your questions by just reading on - there's a lot of book left.

Answer (score 1):

Your question actually boils down to how the function is implemented.
For instance, if factorial looked like this, (can be done with macro as well)

```
(defn factorial
  [n]
  (if (<= n 1) 1 (concat `(~'* ~n) (list (factorial (dec n))))))
```

Upon calling the function,

```
(map #(-> % factorial) (range 10)) =>
(1
 1
 (* 2 1)
 (* 3 (* 2 1))
 (* 4 (* 3 (* 2 1)))
 (* 5 (* 4 (* 3 (* 2 1))))
 (* 6 (* 5 (* 4 (* 3 (* 2 1)))))
 (* 7 (* 6 (* 5 (* 4 (* 3 (* 2 1))))))
 (* 8 (* 7 (* 6 (* 5 (* 4 (* 3 (* 2 1)))))))
 (* 9 (* 8 (* 7 (* 6 (* 5 (* 4 (* 3 (* 2 1)))))))))
```

This would be called.
You can think of macro as function that transforms a function. Only when the function factorial transforms an expression to look like the nested multiplication as above will the macroexpansion give what you are looking for.

```
(map #(-> % factorial eval) (range 10)) ; will give the evaluated values
```